# I can't figure out why my program throws "String Index Out of Range" error (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop

My program is a rough plan for a basic way to encrypt a password, by choosing random numbers and random mathematical operators that are used with the numbers in the "key" string to encrypt the password. But the program throws an error whenever I run it, and after looking through it for a while I can't tell what's causing the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pass = "Password";
    String pwE = "";
    String key = "";
    String keyop = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
        key += (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
        keyop += (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);

    }

    System.out.println(keyop);
    System.out.println(key);

    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < pass.length(); j++) {

            if (keyop.charAt(i) == '1') {
                pwE += " " + (char) (pass.charAt(i) + (key.charAt(j)));
            } else if (keyop.charAt(i) == '2') {
                pwE += (char) (pass.charAt(i) - key.charAt(j));
            } else if (keyop.charAt(i) == '3') {
                pwE += (char) (pass.charAt(i) * key.charAt(j));
            } else if (keyop.charAt(i) == '4') {
                pwE += " " + ((double) (pass.charAt(i) / key.charAt(j))) + " ";
            }
        }
        pass = pwE;
        pwE = "";
    }

    System.out.println(pass);
}
```

Comment: which line does the error get thrown at?

Comment: And what is the exact and complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < pass.length(); j++)` you probably want `key.length()` here ;)

Comment: Now I feel a bit sheepish... Thank you so much

Comment: The length of the inner for-loop is affected by you assigning a new value to _pass_ each time you move to a new iteration of the outer for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above written code has a logic error, you are changing the value of pass at the end of j loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j < pass.length(); j++) {}  pass = pwE;
```

Now of value of pass changes , and exceeds 7, you will get the error "String index out of range 8" at

```
key.charAt(j)
```